# How can I find the rightmost column in a 2D array in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

How can I find the rightmost column in a 2D array in vb.net? I currently have a 2 dimensional array as follows

Dim intArray(0 To 34, 0 To 57) As Integer

I want to find the right most column (highest second number), and UBound only returns the last row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify, the dimension in `UBound()`:

```
numColumns = UBound(intArray, 2) + 1    (assumes zero based)
```

Another example:

```
Dim A(1 To 50, 0 To 10, -3 To 9)

                            Value 
UBound(A, 1)                   50                   
UBound(A, 2)                   10 
UBound(A, 3)                    9
```